# Wrap text using AsposePDF in Java

Tags: java, aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I'm trying to append text on an existing PDF. There is a huge text box(may be a paragraph box?) and when I try to add multiple lines of text, it's flowing out of the box. I'm doing this:

```
TextFragment txtFrag = new TextFragment(str);
        txtFrag .setPosition(100,200);
        txtFrag .getTextState().setFont(new FontRepository().findFont("Arial"));
        txtFrag .getTextState().setFontSize(9.0F);
TextBuilder textBuilder = new TextBuilder(page);
        textBuilder.appendText(txtFrag);
```

The string **`str`** in **`TextFragment(str)`** is a paragraph with multiple lines. How should I achieve text wrapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may set "WordWrapMode" by using below line of code:

```
paragraph.getFormattingOptions().setWrapMode(1);
```

This will keep the text inside the box. You may visit  [WordWrapMode Field](https://apireference.aspose.com/java/pdf/com.aspose.pdf.facades/WordWrapMode) to learn more about it. I hope this will be helpful. Please let us know if you need any further assistance.

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.